# Facebook open graph run story with fitness.course

Tags: ios, facebook, cocoa-touch, facebook-opengraph, facebook-ios-sdk

I am trying to use the Facebook iOS SDK (latest release at time of post) to post a *run* (fitness) Open Graph story. The [Custom Stories](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/open-graph#sharedialog) tutorial explains how to setup basic story posts in my app (note: I am not using a custom story, I am using Facebook's *run* story); and I've made it that far.

The point where I'm stuck is with the `fitness.course` parameter. The [course parameter](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/fitness#) documentation states the following:

> A unique course URL is required for each run, bike, walk published for a user.

If I'm reading the documentation correctly, Facebook will not accept an array of location points. Instead, Facebook wants developers to upload course data to their own server and then pass in the URL of the associated course file on the server? Can someone confirm that's correct?

Is there a way to submit `course` information without hosting it on my own server (as this would be a lot more work than I planned)?

Comment: You can either host the object yourself or use the Object API. Both ways are described at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-objects

Comment: @WizKid can I get sample code? Because I have tried both the ways as mentioned above but no luck. I need exact code to post fitness.course object with fitness.runs action.